# FreeBSD 9.3 date shows UTC when rc.conf and PostgreSQL show "America/Los_Angeles"

Tags: freebsd, clock

We're testing FreeBSD 9.3, where I had the system configured to use *America/Los_Angeles* as the timezone, and we've got the ntp server pointed at pool.ntp.org.  Everything was fine, until I noticed that timestamps were off in some system logs, i.e. they were reporting UTC timestamps for the log entries, instead of local time as they had been reporting previously.

So I went to the console, and sure enough, *date* now reports UTC:

```
# date Thu Jan 15 19:40:22 UTC 2015  <<-- this had been reporting PST
```

However, the rc.conf setting is still there for *America/Los_Angeles*:

```
# grep 'timezone' /etc/rc.conf
timezone="America/Los_Angeles"
```

The PostgreSQL database seems fine:

```
phlog=# show timezone;
      TimeZone
---------------------
 America/Los_Angeles
(1 row)

phlog=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2015-01-15 11:43:44.485139-08
(1 row)
```

Here's our ntp.conf file:

```
# cat /etc/ntp.conf
server pool.ntp.org
restrict default noquery nomodify notrap nopeer
restrict 127.0.0.1
```

I've scanned files in /var/log/ for any clue as to what might have caused the system time to change.

```
# grep ntp messages
Jan 13 23:04:47 test99 ntpd[2702]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Jan 13 23:07:07 test99 ntpd[2724]: ntpd 4.2.4p5-a (1)
Jan 13 23:58:40 test99 ntpd[2726]: time reset +0.156664 s
Jan 15 19:32:48 test99 ntpd[2726]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Jan 15 19:34:48 test99 ntpd[2724]: ntpd 4.2.4p5-a (1)
Jan 15 19:56:12 test99 ntpd[2726]: ntpd exiting on signal 15  <<-- SEE NOTE BELOW
Jan 15 12:58:13 test99 ntpd[2725]: ntpd 4.2.4p5-a (1)
```

NOTE: this was the reboot after setting the timezone to *America/Boise* to see if it would take, it did.  Now date reports:

```
Thu Jan 15 15:09:39 MST 2015
```

**What might have happened to cause the system clock to lose its timezone setting?**

**UPDATE**

I've been reading various resources related to FreeBSD timezone configuration, and found that there should be an */etc/localtime* file in place.  I had looked for this file, and did NOT see it when *date* reported UTC.  After resetting things to a different timezone, I now see that file.  It appears something may have deleted that file.  I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that deleting the file */etc/localtime* causes the symptoms described.

I don't know what's deleting that file in our environment, and that's very likely to be some errant logic in our code base.